# How can I adjust text evenly in WordCloud Python?

Tags: python, word-cloud

I have read the tutorial of the WordCloud Python library: https://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/
But it is not possible to style the words to look even like this one.

[image: Hearth shaped words]

Here is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS, ImageColorGenerator
```

Function handling code

```
txt = '''I would love to try or hear the sample audio your app can produce. I    do not 
want to purchase, because I've purchased so many apps that say they do something and do 
not deliver.  

Can you please add audio samples with text you've converted? I'd love to see the end 
results.

Thanks!

Em là cô gái bán diêm em đói quá

'''

word_cloud = WordCloud(font_path='arial', stopwords=STOPWORDS, background_color="white", 
max_font_size=50, max_words=100)
word_cloud = word_cloud.generate_from_text(get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(txt)))

plt.imshow(word_cloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

If not, please suggest me another way, thanks

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow community. Please clarify what exactly is your question.

Comment: Hello brother, I need to ask how to do Fill a Shape with Text in Python from an existing black and white image and a piece of text. As shown above.